# MySQL max(date) returns max date but other wrong fields

Tags: mysql, date, select, max

I have a table for items purchased in different dates and would like to select only the latest date of each item. But when I use this code:

```
     SELECT `pid`,`price`, MAX(`date`) FROM `products_purchase` GROUP BY `pid`
```

```
id pid      price     date
1  6         2.50    2015-12-8
2  6         2.65    2015-11-23
3  6         3.11    2015-10-14
```

I have looked at many solutions for "**mysql max(date) not working**" but finally noticed that it select the right date but wrong row **it shows the price from other row.**
For example it shows date as 2015-12-8 (which is max date) but price of 2.65 which is from other row.
Please help.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: It's because MySQL is a stupid database that lets you select a field that is not part of the grouping or part of the aggregation. It selects basically a random price per pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the prices arranged by date and cut the first one

```
SELECT pid,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY DATE DESC),',',1)as price,
MAX(date)
FROM products_purchase 
GROUP BY pid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pid,price,date FROM products_purchase GROUP BY pid order by date desc
```

Comment: This may work correctly in current versions of MySQL, but probably won't work in MariaDB (the open source fork of MySQL), nor is it guaranteed to work in future versions of MySQL.

Comment: I don't know about mariaDB. why there is no guarantee to work in future mysql version?

Comment: Because the behaviour is undocumented - you're trying to order by a field that is neither aggregated, nor grouped on, in a grouped query. I'm not even sure whether this version of the query will work in current versions of MySQL, though it may; I would normally put the `order by` in an inline view, then `group by` outside the inline view, but even that has the same issues I mentioned in my first comment.